# Arch Linux: Blueman-applet isn't launching in the status bar

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bluetooth, arch-linux, blueman

I am trying to launch Blueman-applet via [my i3-gaps config](https://github.com/LiterallyJohnny/dotfiles/blob/main/i3/config), but nothing shows up in the status bar.

For some reason, running `blueman-applet` in the terminal gives the following output:

```
[johnny@lj-laptop ~]$ blueman-applet
blueman-applet version 2.1.4 starting
There is an instance already running
```

[You can find my .xsessionerrors file here.](https://gist.github.com/LiterallyJohnny/b7e4b63be2a827fc454a237959844923) Pay close attention to lines 35-37. Those seem to be what's causing the errors.

On my desktop PC, I have the same packages installed and (almost) the same systemd services enabled, and it works fine (for the most part, but Blueman at least launches). I don't believe I should be getting any errors.

[This is a screenshot of my status bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCMFp.png)

Hopefully someone here knows how I could fix this.

[**Click here for system information**](https://github.com/LiterallyJohnny#laptop)

**Edit:** Due to the fact I am using a window manager (i3), I can't autostart `~/.config/autostart` or `/etc/xdg/autostart`. There are programs that do this, but I would rather not use one.

Blueman works correctly on my desktop, and it is being launched directly from my i3 config too.

Comment: Does the following file exist on your system: `/etc/xdg/autostart/blueman.desktop`?

Comment: @Andy yes, it does exist on my system. However, I am using a window manager (i3), so I autostart all of my applications directly from the i3 config file.